# Solr 6.6 - Find and group query by first character

Tags: solr

We have task to find posts by related city names, and group results by city name incl. number of posts.

In our location field we have one or more city names separated by comma:

Berlin, Frankfurt,..

```
<field name="location" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

We must looking for location only by first character, example

f (lowercase): Frankfurt (Uppercase) - 1200 posts, Freiburg - 690 posts, ...

in our php / CakePHP code we have http query bulider like:

```
    $fq = sprintf('location:%s*', mb_strtoupper($char));

    $getResponse = $http->get($solrUrl, [
        'facet.pivot' => 'location',
        'facet.sort' => 'count',
        'facet.limit' => 10000,
        'facet.offset' => 0,
        'facet' => 'true',
        'facet.pivot.mincount' => 5,
        'indent' => 'on',
        'fq'=> $fq,
        'wt' => 'json'
    ]);
```

response:

```
[
    'error' => [
        'metadata' => [
            (int) 0 => 'error-class',
            (int) 1 => 'org.apache.solr.common.SolrException',
            (int) 2 => 'root-error-class',
            (int) 3 => 'org.apache.solr.common.SolrException'
        ],
        'msg' => 'analyzer returned no terms for multiTerm term: F',
        'code' => (int) 400
    ]
]
```

How to create right query for our task?

Comment: Be aware that a text field will split its content into tokens based on whitespace etc., so if you have a name such as `Freiberg am Neckar`, it'll be retrieved for `Freiberg`, `am` and `Neckar`. My initial guess is that this is not what you want. Use a string field instead for faceting, which probably will make your filter work properly as well (as no analysis will take place).

Comment: I would suggest to alter your schema and indexing process. Make that city field multivalued, split those multi-city-strings by comma and have each city as own field value. Moreover add a new multivalued field that will contain the starting letters of each city. This will be not much work, but way better in terms of performance.